# C Passing a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
static void increment(long long *n){
  (*n)++;
}

static void mult2(long long *n){
  (*n) = (*n)*2;
}

struct counter{
  long long counter;
};

struct counter* cp = malloc(sizeof(struct counter));
cp[0].counter = 5;
increment(cp);

printf("Expecting a 6 : %lld.\n", cp[0].counter);
```

Hi, This is a part of my code where I actually want to increment or x2 a counter,
but I kept getting error on the argument and argument type.

Comment: what errors do you get? where? what lines?

Comment: "I kept getting error"? What error? What line? What did the error say?

Comment: struct count and long long are different types, aren't they?

Comment: passing argument 1 of 'increment' from incompatible pointer type at static void increment

Comment: fixed it, Thanks moron. cp[0].counter instead of cp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

struct count and long long are different types.

Try

`increment(&(cp->counter));`

Usage of `cp[0].counter = 5` instead of `cp->counter = 5` is quite bizzare, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `struct counter *` into a function that expects a `long long *`. That won't work. You probably meant `increment(&(cp[0].counter))`.